# Web Application with React and Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am a new Nodejs developer and I wanted to understand a few things about creating a web app with react and express.

I want to do the following:

-> My web applications will have around 5 static pages which include the home page, about us page etc. From my reading, I understand that these static pages will need to be rendered server side for SEO optimization.

-> I am also creating a user dashboard which will be made completely in react to serve as a single page application once the user logs in.

-> Thirdly, I also want to have a portion of the web app render different content based on url. For example: mywebsite/test1 should render content about test1 while mywebsite/test2 should render content about test2. I understand that this can be done through react but because I also want these urls to be SEO so the content will have to be rendered serverside.

How would I go setting up such an application? My initial thoughts are as follows:

Have an express app where I have routes defined for the 5 static pages. I can render html directly for these 5 pages.

For the dashboard, I can have an express route forward the request to react/react router and take it from there.

Similarly for the 3rd part I was use the express route to direct to a react component.

Is this the right way to go about it?

Thanks! Do let me know if I missing something or if I'm conceptually wrong about something.

Comment: This question is far too broad. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

All I understand is that you're doing some kind of isomorphic app.

1. Static pages can be pre-rendered at build (index.html, about.html, etc)
2. Serve static files from a subfolder (i.e. `/assets`)
3. When requested URL is prefixed with i.e. `/dashboard`, make express serve your dashboard:

   `http://example/dashboard/some/view` => `/dashboard.html`
4. In your dashboard, you'll probably use [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).
   Your Router will then dispatch URLs to desired components:

   `import { Route } from 'react-router';
   import SomeView from 'app/components/some/SomeView.jsx';
   <Route path='/dashboard/some/view' render={SomeView} />`

You'll find a lot of examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example) or articles [here](http://jlongster.com/Presenting-The-Most-Over-Engineered-Blog-Ever) or [here](https://reactjsnews.com/isomorphic-react-in-real-life) related to isomorphic apps.